# MySQL use lowercase for schema and table names. How to set default uppercase without changing lower_case_table_names variable?

Tags: mysql, flyway

I run flyway scripts DDL and DML where we use uppercase, but mysql use lowercase. Is there exist how to set default uppercase? TQ

Comment: Without changing the variable that controls this? It's not doable.

Comment: I agree, I don't think you can change this unless you change the variable the is meant to be used to change it. Kind of a chicken-and-egg problem. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is resolved by changing lower_case_table_names variable during instalation of mysql in advanced option.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).